# Paging month-by-month in the Calendar application

Tags: ipad, calendar, ios

In the prior version of iOS I was able to navigate the monthly view of the calendar page-by-page: sweeping left advanced the view to the next month, while sweeping right brought me back to the prior month.

After the upgrade to iOS-7 I am no longer able to navigate my calendar page-by-page: the view is in the smooth scroll mode, which is sometimes confusing.

Did I miss some setting or a new gesture to lock in a month and enable page-by-page navigation, or is this simply the way the things are going to be from now on?

Comment: swipe from the middle of the screen.

Comment: @Buscar웃 This does not appear to work for me :-(